# removeAttribute() doesn't work DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Why doesn't `removeAttribute()` remove anything in the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        Element with style.
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="DelStyle()">
        Remove the style attribute from the element
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DelStyle() {
            var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            console.log(div)
            div.style.border = 'solid #3B3B3D 1px';
            console.log(div)
            div.removeAttribute("style");
            console.log(div)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In `div.style.border = 'solid #3B3B3D 1px';` you are not setting the element's style *attribute*, you are only setting the object's style *property*.

Comment: Following on from @arnaud576875's comment, you can use `setAttribute` and then `removeAttribute` will work: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/tFxMm/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are making all these changes at once before the DOM updates.  Instead consider actually setting the style attribute to nothing see **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MKeuB/2)**

```
        div.setAttribute("style","");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just call getAttribute("style") before removeAttribute("style").

e.g.

```
    function DelStyle() {
        var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        console.log(div)
        div.style.border = 'solid #3B3B3D 1px';
        console.log(div)
        div.getAttribute("style");
        div.removeAttribute("style");
        console.log(div)
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/qTv22/

This looks very much like a Chrome JS optimization bug. Although the HTML5 spec says

> The style IDL attribute must return a CSSStyleDeclaration whose value
>   represents the declarations specified in the attribute, if present.
>   Mutating the CSSStyleDeclaration object must create a style attribute
>   on the element (if there isn't one already) and then change its value
>   to be a value representing the serialized form of the
>   CSSStyleDeclaration object. The same object must be returned each
>   time.

Chrome is trying to defer the creating of the style attribute for as long as it can, so that a series of mutations of the IDL attribute can be rolled up into a single creation/change of the content attribute. The code is simply omitting to perform the create/change action before the removeAttribute call, but does so correctly for getAttribute. Once the content attribute has been created, removeAttribute will successfully destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

As [advised on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute), one should use removeAttribute over setting to null or empty string.

It may not work properly though and the solution is to use requestAnimationFrame or setInterval if the less standard browser you want to target doesn't support RAF.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it needs a more time, [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/P7paB/)

```
function DelStyle() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    console.log(div)
    div.style.border = 'solid #3B3B3D 1px';
    console.log(div)
    setTimeout((function(div) {
        return function() {
            div.removeAttribute("style");
            console.log(div);
        }
    })(div), 500);

}
```

I'm removingAttribute after a half second.

Comment: using a timeout is not the best way and won't be the fastest.

Comment: @Joseph, no but it demonstrates why removeAttribute was not working.

Comment: @Joey ah I see! take a look at my comment on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165359/removeattribute-doesnt-work-dom/7165473#7165473#7165436).  I see the same problem with this example.  Chrome bug maybe? Edit: D: it's gone!

Comment: @Joseph I deleted my post because I realized I was confusing the DOM "style" attribute with the JS DOM "style" property. Here's your comment, in reply to me saying this doesn't work: "I just discovered the weirdest thing... yes .style does physically add a style attribute and you can inspect the element and it's there. in theory you should be able to remove attribute too, but this only works when I have my js console up (ctrl+shift+j). I theorize that that is because in logging the element in it's current state, chrome also updates it. If the console.logs are removed, it breaks. (Chrome 13)"

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeremy Banks for reposting it :)  This truely is the weirdest thing I've seen in chrome. :S

Comment: @Joseph - To understand why an attribute is created from the property (aka IDL attribute) and what seems to be happening in Chrome, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Test this

```
div.attributes.removeNamedItem("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with removeProperty and removeAttribute. I solved it by writing the original instance of that property/attribute inline in my html instead of my css.

Answer (score -1):

I tried calling both the `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` methods before calling `removeAttribute()`.

It didn't work for me: Neither did setting the style attribute to nothing.

What did work was to use the `removeAttributeNode()` method.

As described here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattributenode.asp the result will be the same; e.g.

> ```
> function DelStyle() {
>     var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
>     console.log(div)
>     div.style.border = 'solid #3B3B3D 1px';
>     console.log(div)
>     div.removeAttributeNode(div.getAttribute("style"));
>     console.log(div)
> }
> ```