# removeAttribute('style') not working in iOS, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I have mobile version of the site. I use touchemove event to move page to the left and to the right with -webkit-transform. This transform is an inline property of element. On touchend i use `document.getElementById('element').removeAttribute("style");` but it's not working on mobile phones and tablets.

How to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: It seems you can't remove default attributes... once try : `document.getElementById('element').setAttribute('style','');`

Comment: should work... chack if document.getElementById('element') is returning any element.

Comment: @Mr_Green, style attribute can be removed using removeAttribute.

Comment: @Ahsan Shah, no you don't right. iOS has this problem Mr_Green gave the right advice!

Comment: @DenimTornado you can post solution as answer as well to help others

Comment: @AhsanShah why would someone wants to remove a default attribute. just making it empty is enough I think.

Comment: @Mr_Green agreed with you. i was thinking to remove it as it is an optional attribute

Comment: @Ahsan Shah, can't do that: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Appears to be fixed, for those interested, in iOS13. But nulling the attribute doesn't work in iOS12.4. Haven't found anything that does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removeAttribute() doesn't work DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165359/removeattribute-doesnt-work-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes if you are making more changes at once, `removeAttribute` seems doesn't work. Instead use `setAttribute` method something like this:

```
document.getElementById('element').setAttribute('style','');
```

Calling `getAttribute` before `removeAttribute` also seems to work though but I suggest not to remove default attributes.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167553/1577396)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that using

```
element.getAttribute('style');
element.removeAttribute('style');
```

has worked reliably for me in the past. According to the MDN using `removeAttribute` is preferred over using `setAttribute` to set it to an empty value (though, to be fair, the documents don't actually say *why* this is preferred).

> You should use `removeAttribute` instead of setting the attribute value to `null` using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) – (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute).

Comment: This helped me remove style attribute. It was blank after `removeAttribute('style')` but with `getAttribute('style')` first helps remove it completely for some reason. Thanks!